# Conditional navigation properties in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I'm trying to create a navigation property in EF Core that would setup its reference conditionally based off the values of two properties. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Let me show you an example: let's say I have a hierarchical structure of entities, such as `Country`, `State`, `County`, and `City`. I also have an entity called `Law`, which could be "owned" by any of the hierarchical entities.

So, I create this enum:

```
public enum OwnerType
{
    Country,
    State,
    County,
    City
}
```

...and the `Law` class:

```
public class Law
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OwnerType OwnerType { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to setup the `Law` class to have a navigation property that would link `OwnerId` to the Primary Key of the corresponding entity based off of the `OwnerType` value.

I considered adding this to the `Law` class:

```
public virtual object Owner { get; set; }
```

Or to create an `IOwner` interface that each of the hierarchical entities would implement and then I'd add this instead:

```
public virtual IOwner Owner { get; set; }
```

But then I have no idea how to setup the `EntityTypeConfiguration` with the `EntityTypeBuilder`. This obviously won't work:

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Owner).WithMany(x => x.Laws).HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);
```

I really just have no idea how to accomplish what I'm trying to do here. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to draw class diagram and you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have 4 different relations and you want to handle them with one foreign key what's a bad idea in concept. If you have 4 relations - you need to have 4 FKs.

In pure OOP you could use and `IOwner` interface but Entity Framework requires explicit information to map your relations respectively and I believe that's the best way. Just add 4 different nullable FKs and validate `Law` state with `OwnerType` value.

```
public class Law {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OwnerType OwnerType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Country)]
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(State)]
    public int? StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(County)]
    public int? CountyId { get; set; }
    public County County { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(City)]
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }

    private void Validate() {
        switch (OwnerType)
        {
            case OwnerType.Coutnry:
                if(CountryId == null)
                    throw new LawValidationException("Country is requried");
            break;
            case OwnerType.State:
                if(StateId == null)
                    throw new LawValidationException("State is requried");
            break;
            case OwnerType.County:
                if(CountyId == null)
                    throw new LawValidationException("County is requried");
            break;
            case OwnerType.City:
                if(CityId == null)
                    throw new LawValidationException("City is requried");
            break;
            default:
                    throw new LawValidationException("Invalid law owner type");
        }
    }
}
```

This approach solves your problem, perfectly fits to Entity Framework abilities and can be easily integrated into external logic including unit tests.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be my only option. There are two reasons I was trying to do it in one FK relationship: 1). to avoid having to add all this code to every entity that can be "owned" by one of these `OwnerType`s, and 2). if I add a new `OwnerType` in the future, I wouldn't have to go back and manually update every entity to have a new nullable FK. I'm fine if there's no way to do it.

Comment: If your entities are not inherited from other base classes yet you can add `OwnedEntity` class (for example), export all these FKs there and then inherit you `Law` and other classes from it. Then you just need to add another migration and Entity Framework will detect model change and update DB schema accordingly. In this case you'll still need to update code every time a new `OwnerType` appears but do it only in one place.